# Blue J shows it is running, but will not open result window

Tags: java, execution, bluej

I have been running a program that simulates the number of steps it will take to get across a 7-step bridge.  A random number is generated to determine if the person takes a step forwards or backwards.  This simulation is run 1000 times.  After this the average number of steps it takes to get across is out printed, as well as the maximum number of steps it took.

This, in turn is run 1000 times.  It compiles fine.  My issue is that when I go to run it, (on BlueJ) the bar shows that it is running but the output window fails to appear.  What is happening? (Most likely is something stupidly obvious that I am oblivious to.)

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Prog214a
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        Random rn = new Random(); 

        for (int m = 1; m <= 20; m++)
        {

            int max = 0;         

            for (int c = 1; c <= 1000; c++)
            {
                int s = 0;
                int sn = 0;
                int sum = 0;

                while (s < 7)
                {
                    int ans = rn.nextInt(1) + 0;

                    if (ans == 1) {
                        s = s + 1
                    }
                    else {
                        s = s - 1;  
                    }

                    sn++;            
                }   

                sum = sum + sn; 

                if (sn > max) {            
                    max = sn;        
                }

                if (c == 1000) {            
                    double avg = sum / c;
                    System.out.print(avg);
                    System.out.print("  " + max);             
                }
            }   
        } 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Please indent/format your code correctly. In BlueJ you can press ctrl+shift+I to do this automatically.

Comment: `s = s + 1` - You are missing the semicolon after this statement. Are you sure this code compiled properly?

Comment: @Flightless_bird, using and IDE is wonderful you should also learn debugging using the IDE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is at least one problem. Here:

```
                int ans = rn.nextInt(1) + 0;

                if (ans == 1){
                    s = s + 1;
                }

                else {
                    s = s -1;  
                }
```

`rn.nextInt(1)` can only return 0, so `ans` will be 0. You have no guard to ensure that `s` does not go negative, so it does - and it remains less than 7, meaning that the while loop (with condition `s < 7`) goes on for a *long* time (specifically, until `s` wraps back to a positive number again).

Comment: And the appropiate call statement will be int ans = rn.nextInt(2); That is to generate 0 or 1 randomly. But yes the execution may not come to rest in finite iterations.

Comment: Thanks for all the help, everybody, I was able to fix all my large errors.  Just one more thing...My avg keeps coming up as 0.  I thought that it was an inheritance thing, so I played around with the positioning of the "c" and "avg", but could not find a way to resolve this issue.  Any suggestions?

Comment: @Flightless_bird you need to move `int sum = 0;` outside the loop. Because it is inside the loop, its value is reset every iteration.